# calling cmd from python windows error 2

Tags: python, windows

I am tring to call the cmd command "move" from python.

```
  cmd1 = ["move", spath , npath]
  startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
  startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

While the comammand works in the cmd. I can move files. With this python code i get:

> WindowsError: [Error 2] The system
>   cannot find the file specified

Spath and npath, are absolute paths to folders, so being in another directory should not matter.

**[edit]**
Responding to Tim's answear: The how do i move a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`move` is built-in into the `cmd` shell, so it's not a file command that you can call this way.

You could use [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), but this "forgets" all alternate data stream, ACLs etc.

Answer (score 2):

try to use `cmd1 = ["cmd", "/c", "move", spath, npath]`